# How do I make this PHP/HTML page have 3 columns instead of two?

Tags: php, html, css

Right now, it pulls data from a MySQL database and puts the data (names) in two side-by-side columns. How do I make this 3? I'm no PHP/HTML/CSS expert. It's just supposed to pull the names of the donors from the database and display them, for digital signage purposes.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM donor WHERE DonationAmount = 1000 AND Category = '2' ORDER BY LastName ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$i = 0;
$total_rows = $result->num_rows;
echo "<table><tr>";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<p style=font-size:20px;>In Honor Of</p>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        // test if the DisplayName field is empty or not
    echo "<td>";
    if(empty($row['DisplayName']))
    {
            // it's empty!
            if(empty($row['FirstName'])){
                    echo $row['LastName'];
            }

            else{
                    echo $row["LastName"]. ", " . $row["FirstName"];
            }

    }else{
            // Do stuff with the field
            echo $row["DisplayName"]. "";
    }
    echo "</td>";
    $i++;
    if($i % 2 == 0 && $i != $total_rows) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

  }
} else {

}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp

Comment: Are you echoing a p directly inside a tr? Perhaps you should do some debugging first, before starting on augmentations.

Comment: @MrLister, what is the issue with the <p> inside a <tr>? I'm just wondering, as I'm not an expert

Comment: @DakotaWagner You can't just put random elements inside one another in HTML. HTML documents are supposed to have a _structure_! And the fact that your browser displays something that looks like what you wanted it to display doesn't make what you made correct! Try with a different browser; it will probably look different, since not all browsers have the same error handling routines. And even if it looks OK in all browsers you can test now, what about browsers you can't test? The best thing you can do is play it safe and keep it error-free. That way, bugs won't come back to hurt you later.

Comment: Ehm, I meant, a tr can only contain th or td elements as children.

Comment: @MrLister okay, so if I remove the <p> and just do the text it would be a more permissible way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here [MOD](http://php.net/manual/tr/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)

```
$column = 3;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM donor WHERE DonationAmount = 1000 AND Category = '2' ORDER BY LastName ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$i = 0;
$total_rows = $result->num_rows;

echo "<h2>In Honor Of</h2>";

echo "<table><tr>";
if ($total_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        // test if the DisplayName field is empty or not
    echo "<td>";
    if(empty($row['DisplayName']))
    {
            // it's empty!
            if(empty($row['FirstName'])){
                    echo $row['LastName'];
            }

            else{
                    echo $row["LastName"]. ", " . $row["FirstName"];
            }

    }else{
            // Do stuff with the field
            echo $row["DisplayName"]. "";
    }
    echo "</td>";
    $i++;

    /*i % column */
    if($i % $column == 0 && $i != $total_rows) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

  }
} else {

}
echo "</tr></table>";
```